# error occurs every time i want to import my database = SQL Query Error and #1064

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to import my database to PhPMyAdmin but this error occurs and I don't know what to do.

SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE CommentZ 
(
CommentID CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
EmployeeID INT NOT NULL,
Dates DATE NOT NULL,
Email VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
Comment_ VARCHAR NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_CommentZ PRIMARY KEY(CommentID),
CONSTRAINT FK_CommentZ1 FOREIGN KEY(EmployeeID) REFERENCES Employee(EmployeeID)
)
```

MySQL said:

> Documentation
>       #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL,
>       CONSTRAINT PK_CommentZ PRIMARY KEY(CommentID),
>       CONSTRAINT FK_Comment' at line 7

Comment: Put a length after `VARCHAR`.

Comment: About the lengths, `VARCHAR(30)` is maybe not enough for storing email addresses

Comment: You also might want to add `Engine = innoDB` after `)` because of the `FOREIGN KEY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define a length for the `VARCHAR` fields

Change this :

```
Comment_ VARCHAR NOT NULL
```

To this

```
Comment_ VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
```

Note that 255 is an arbitrary value. You can use any integer value to define the maximum length of that field